# Shell form does not validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why in this code after click on button get error: http://jsfiddle.net/FyUgH/

> {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name':
>   u'initial-js_lib', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field':
>   ,
>   'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}"}

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button id="cli">Submit</button>
</form>


$('#cli').live('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    alert('oo')
        if($('input[type="text"]').val()=='')alert('input is empty')
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove additional

```
})
```

It should look like

```
$('#cli').live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('oo')
    if($('input[type="text"]').val()=='')alert('input is empty')
});
```